# Why submit button does't call controller function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a small problem with calling controller function. Strange is that every other submit button works fine. But this one has problem which I cannot solve for now. 
I will show you two forms with submit buttons becouse there is only one working fine.

Controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MethodOne()
        {
            ...
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }

    public ActionResult MethodTwo()
        {
            ...
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }
}
```

And the view:

```
//This one works fine!!
@using (Html.BeginForm("MethodOne", "My", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input id="Some-cool-id" type="submit" value="Add!" />
}

//This one doesn't work?!
@using (Html.BeginForm("MethodTwo", "My", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input id="some-cool-id2" type="submit" value="Delete"!" />
}
```

Error is telling that Method2 is not in the required path.

```
Resource not found.

Description: HTTP 404. Searched resource (or ...) ... 

Required path URL: /My/MethodTwo
```

I was searching what is bad but in the end, I need a help, thanks.

Comment: I have tried delete cache and restart Visual studio.

Comment: If it can does problem, in the second form I am creating webgrid before submit button. However only showing him (don't working with data yet)

Comment: Erm... `"Delete"!"` -- got an extra `"` in there? (unless this is a copy-paste error)

Comment: That's just copy paste error. In project it is correct. Sorry for that - anyway good observation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("MethodTwo", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="asd" />
    }


     @using (Html.BeginForm("MethodOne", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="poll" />
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public class TestController : Controller
    {

 public ActionResult MethodOne()
        {

        return RedirectToAction("CustomerInfo");
    }

    public ActionResult MethodTwo()
    {

        return RedirectToAction("CustomerInfo");
    }

 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CustomerInfo()
        {

        ViewBag.CustomerNameID = new SelectList(List, "CustomerId", "customerName");
        ViewBag.RegisterItems = GetAllRegisterData();
        ViewData["SampleList"] = GetAllRegisterData();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem was not there. Still falling.

Comment: @Ademar both the form is in same page?

Comment: Yes in the same page (View)...
Really? Then I try make new controller and copy there functions.

Comment: @Ademar I just update my code. It's an example and it's perfectly working fine.

Comment: Well, I have tried create new controller and copy there all Actions. And do you know what? It started work fine. I have't got emplanation how it is possible. So thanks, found error mainly thanks you:)

Answer (score 1):

Add the property `[HttpPost]` before the method.

Comment: Didn't help, unfortunately. :(

Comment: What is the routing rule?